# How to correctly null terminate a c string?

Tags: c

I have the following code which counts the number of occurrences of each unique term in a text document.  I believe I correctly terminated each c-string with `'\0'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ()
{
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    int NUMBER_OF_WORDS = 100;
    int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 30;

    char uniqueWords[NUMBER_OF_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
    int wordCount[NUMBER_OF_WORDS];
    int uniqueWordIndex =0;

    char tempWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
    int tempWordIndex = 0;

    file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF && uniqueWordIndex < 100){
            if( isalpha(c)){
                tempWord[tempWordIndex] = c;
                tempWordIndex++;
            }else if ( (c == ' ' || c == '\n') && strlen(tempWord) > 0  ) {
                tempWord[tempWordIndex] = '\0';
                int k = 0;
                int newUnique = 1;
                for (k=0; k<NUMBER_OF_WORDS; k++){
                    if (strcmp (tempWord, uniqueWords[k]) == 0){
                        wordCount[k]++;
                        newUnique = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (newUnique){
                    int i=0;
                    wordCount[uniqueWordIndex] = 1;
                    for (i=0; i<strlen(tempWord); i++)
                        uniqueWords[uniqueWordIndex][i] = tempWord[i];
                    uniqueWords[uniqueWordIndex][i] = '\0';
                    uniqueWordIndex++;
                }

                tempWordIndex = 0;

            }
        }
        int i =0;
        for (i =0; i< NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++){
            int k = 0;
            for (k =0; k< strlen(uniqueWords[i]); k++)
                printf("%c",uniqueWords[i][k]);
                printf(" %d\n", wordCount[i]);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Is there any syntax error that's resulting in wacky output like this?

```
term 2
something 5
reading 1
level 1
!J<8F><FF>^? 0
<C8>B~8<91>^? 0
```

Comment: This output does not match with the given code.Is there something else you want to tell us?

Comment: Have you ran your code through `gdb`? If not, why not? Problems like these are what debuggers are made for...

Comment: Why can you use `printf`, `strlen` and `strcmp` but not `scanf` or `strcpy`? This seems like an example of *using the wrong tool for the job*, to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not guaranteed to have `NUMBER_OF_WORDS` entries in `uniqueWords` or `wordCount`, but you are printing out that many at the end. Whether or not that is responsible for the output you are seeing, it would be likely to produce such output if your input has less than `NUMBER_OF_WORDS` unique words.

Comment: Indeed. That loop should probably terminate when `i == uniqueWordIndex`.